# How to stop dead code elimination for one particular statement in Angular 7

Tags: javascript, angular, angular7, minify, dead-code

I am using bootstrap carousel for my angular 7 project. One of the statement for carousel animation is as below, which basically reflows the screen.

`$next[0].offsetWidth`

Now, when generating prod build, angular removes this line (during minification) as this statement is not meaningful and not subsequently used. Due to which, screen doesn't reflow correctly and it breaks the animation.

I have made a fix with help of console.log as below.

`var dontMinifyMe = $next[0].offsetWidth`
`console.log(dontMinifyMe)`

I was wondering if there is any better way to do it, as constant console.logs due to this are annoying and messes up the console.

Comment: You could probably assign it to itself too. `$next[0].offsetWidth = $next[0].offsetWidth` but there's gotta be a nicer solution.

Comment: @CertainPerformance This will give js error as offsetWidth is a getter and can not be set. Any other solution?